# Support for setting ACL in Linux

Tags: java, linux, acl, jna

I understand from Java 7 onwards I can use a code like the below to set ACL for a file:

```
    java.nio.file.Path file = Paths.get(filePath);

    java.nio.file.attribute.GroupPrincipal joe = file.getFileSystem().getUserPrincipalLookupService()
            .lookupPrincipalByGroupName(groupid);

    AclFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(file, AclFileAttributeView.class);
    java.nio.file.attribute.AclEntry entry = java.nio.file.attribute.AclEntry.newBuilder()
            .setType(AclEntryType.ALLOW)
            .setPrincipal(joe)
            .setPermissions(aclEntryPermissions)
            .build();

            List<java.nio.file.attribute.AclEntry> acl = view.getAcl();
    acl.add(entry);
    view.setAcl(acl);
```

But this code wont run for Linux (runs fine for Windows and Solaris). And the reason seems to be because `AclFileAttributeView` is not supported in Linux.

My questions are:

1. Is there some version of Java where `AclFileAttributeView` is supported in Linux?
2. If answer to 1 is no, then can someone share a sample JNA code, or give me some pointers to the Native API I need to use in Linux, to get this running.

In effect I want the functionality similar to the `setfacl` and `getfacl` command lines.

Comment: `AclFileAttributeView` isn't always supported on solaris. It depends on the filesystem you're looking at.  You need to back out to a larger scope and answer the question of "what purpose are these ACL examinations serving?".